# Почему при попытке вызвать функцию в РНР коде я получаю 500-ю ошибку?

Tags: php, функции

Как задать одну функцию для данного набора файлов без конфликтов?
Есть файл `index.php` внутри которого подключаются ещё нескольких php-файлов.
Как сделать, чтобы php-функцию, объявленную в `index.php` можно было использовать без `500 ошибки` в каждом подключаемом файле:

```
function fileVersion($some) {
  $first = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/'.$some;
  $some = $some.'?ver=';
  $some = $some.filemtime($first);
  return $some;
}
```

Comment: надо прочитать, какую ошибку вызывает код, и исправить её

Answer (score 0):

функция должна быть объявлена **до** подключения php файлов в которых она вызывается.

Comment: А если подумать? Ну или документацию почитать?